# Emacs Org Mode: How To Stop Total in Column View Showing Number of Days?

Tags: emacs, formatting, org-mode

I'm using Emacs 23.4.1 and Org-Mode 8.0.6

In my org file I have the estimated number of hours that a task will take using the `Effort` property of the associated heading. For example:

```
* My Tasks
** TODO Read a book...
** TODO Watch a film...
** TODO Learn org-mode
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Effort:  2:00
   :END:
```

Then I can switch to column view and view the total time estimated for all of "my tasks". I do this by adding the following line to my org file:

```
#+COLUMNS: %55ITEM(Details) %5Effort(Time){:}
```

When the total number of hours is greater than 24, then the total is displayed in terms of days and hours, e.g. `3d 14`. *How can I format the display so that it tells me the total number of hours (and minutes), rather than breaking it into days?*

(In short, I want the total effort of "My Tasks" to display `86:00`, rather than `3d 14`.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See the var org-time-clocksum-format:

```
;; format string used when creating CLOCKSUM lines and when generating a
;; time duration (avoid showing days)
(setq org-time-clocksum-format
      '(:hours "%d" :require-hours t :minutes ":%02d" :require-minutes t))
```

Comment: See the answer by @samim. In a recent org-mode update the `org-time-clocksum-format` and other were deprecated in favor of `org-duration-format`. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-02/msg00270.html

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer did not work for me. I was going to display `CLOCKSUM` in hours. This worked:

`(setq org-duration-format 'h:mm)`