# Emacs Org Mode: Change Time Format in Clock Table to Decimal Number

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to change the time format in my clock tables (C-c C-x C-r). I know from [1] that the variable in question is "org-time-clocksum-format", but I dont know how to change the format in order to gain the following objectives:

1. Show time in hours as a float (7.1666 instead of 7:10 resp. 7 hours and 10 minutes)
2. Show time in percentage of sum (so if an entry took 2 hours and the sum is 8 hours, it should show 20% or something alike)

I use Org-mode version 8.3beta and Emacs 24.3;

[1] [Emacs Org Mode: How To Stop Total in Column View Showing Number of Days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929979/emacs-org-mode-how-to-stop-total-in-column-view-showing-number-of-days)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to customize the clock display to fractional values by setting `org-time-clocksum-use-fractional` to non-nil.

Answer (score 3):

to get percentages try to add `:formula %` to your clocktable parameters. this gives you another column with percentages.